# Find row value based on one column in another column and do calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```python
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'start':['2020-08-01','2020-08-02','2020-08-03','2020-08-04','2020-08-05','2020-08-06','2020-08-07','2020-08-08'],
                     'end':['2020-08-03','2020-08-03','2020-08-06','2020-08-06','2020-08-06','2020-08-08','2020-08-08','2020-08-08'],
                     'score':[74, 81, 38, 49, 79, 17, 53, 69]})
```

that I need to compute the `score` difference between `start` date and its corresponding `end` date as:

```python
         start         end  score  result
0   2020-08-01  2020-08-03     74      36  # 74-38 as score on 08/03 is 38
1   2020-08-02  2020-08-03     81      43  # 81-38
2   2020-08-03  2020-08-06     38      21  # 38-17 as score on 08/06 is 17
3   2020-08-04  2020-08-06     49      32  # 49-17
4   2020-08-05  2020-08-06     79      62  # 79-17
5   2020-08-06  2020-08-08     17     -52  # 17-69 as score on 08/08 is 69
6   2020-08-07  2020-08-08     53     -16  # 53-69
7   2020-08-08  2020-08-08     69       0  # 69-69
```

Is there a good `pandas` way to do this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use if all `start` values are unique subtracting by mapped values:

```
data['result'] = data['score'].sub(data['end'].map(data.set_index('start')['score']))
print (data)
        start         end  score  result
0  2020-08-01  2020-08-03     74      36
1  2020-08-02  2020-08-03     81      43
2  2020-08-03  2020-08-06     38      21
3  2020-08-04  2020-08-06     49      32
4  2020-08-05  2020-08-06     79      62
5  2020-08-06  2020-08-08     17     -52
6  2020-08-07  2020-08-08     53     -16
7  2020-08-08  2020-08-08     69       0
```

**Detail**:

```
print (data['end'].map(data.set_index('start')['score']))
0    38
1    38
2    17
3    17
4    17
5    69
6    69
7    69
Name: end, dtype: int64
```